# How to make specific files to zero byte files

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of *.FLAC files in different subfolders, which I want to turn into zero byte files, for database use only. I have the following code, but it makes all files to zero bytes. I don‘t know, how to fit the code. Maybe you can help? Thanks!

```
$Path='G:\Music\' 
$Files=Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse | Where-Object  {($_.Length) -gt 0} 
    ForEach ($File in $Files) { New-Item$File.FullName -Force -Value '' }
```

Comment: Basically you wanna replace all your *.FLAC for zero byte files (with the same name they already have) on all subfolders. Is that correct?

Comment: Filter for those files: `$Files=Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "*.FLAC" -File -Recurse`, this way only those with the extension of `.FLAC` get stored in your variable. Use `Get-Help Get-ChildItem` to brush up on the syntax/parameters that are offered in the cmdlet

Comment: Yes. Same name, no change. Only make it to zero byte.

Comment: Thanks, will try later.

Filter for those files: $Files=Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "*.FLAC" -File -Recurse, this way only those with the extension of .FLAC get stored in your variable. Use Get-Help Get-ChildItem to brush up on the syntax/parameters that are offered in the cmdlet – Abraham Zinala 4 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can replace all your FLAC files for zero byte FLAC files recursively. You can use a normal `foreach loop` or pipe to `foreach-object`.

You don't really need to check if the FLAC file's length is greater than 0 but you can also add that condition.

```
$Path='G:\Music' # Define parent path
$Files=Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse -Filter *.FLAC # Get all FLAC files recursively

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $null > $file.FullName
}

# OR using foreach-object (same result)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse -Filter *.FLAC | ForEach-Object {$null > $_.FullName}
```

Edit:

Adding these 2 examples below for PS 5.1. As it seems, `$null > file` doesn't create an actual zero byte file on this PS version, see below comments from @mklement0 for more info.

```
# Example 1 (Not efficient)
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse -Filter *.FLAC | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force
}

# Example 2
New-Item -Force (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Filter *.FLAC).FullName
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help @MaxHeadroom

Comment: @mklement0 good to know, I was testing on PS Core didn't know for PS 5.1 the files were not 0 byte. The correct syntax should be `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Filter *.FLAC | New-Item -Value $null -Force` ? This is giving me 0 length files on PS Core too.

Comment: No, as it turns out you cannot robustly use pipeline input in this case, because the input file-info objects bind by their file _name_ only to the `-Name` parameter. You can pipe to `ForEach-Object` and call `New-Item` in its script block, using `$_.FullName`, or you can even do the following, which will perform much better: `New-Item -Force (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse -Filter *.FLAC).FullName -WhatIf`

Comment: Good to know, I added your examples to the edits. Thanks @mklement0.

Comment: Thanks for updating, @SantiagoSquarzon (+1). Re not creating a zero-byte file with `$null>`: In _Windows PowerShell_ (versions up to v5.1), `>` creates "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files, which always have a 2-byte BOM. Therefore, even when writing nothing, you'll end up with a _2-byte_ file. You can work around that with `Set-Content -NoNewLine -Value $null`; the latter command also meaningfully accepts _pipeline input_ from `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` - unlike `New-Item -Force`, which is otherwise the simplest choice for all versions. Use `-WhatIf` to _preview_ the operation.